# Assertion Issue of jsonpath response

Tags: karate, gherkin

I'm writing api test automated codes with bdd method by Karate.
Assertion part pushes me hard. My response is like below, and when I called that path `$.data.subscribers[0].products` this gives me empty-null array as I checked by http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ website. However, when I run my gherkin Karate feature then It gave me the response as null, It still gives me error assertion. It says actual:

> null, expected: null...

I couldn't see any error, how can I fix this? Is it a bug or Is there any method to handle it?

My response:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "return_code": 0,
    "message": "success"
  },
  "data": {
    "sbs": [
      {
        "sbs_id": 32432432,
        "dt": "OTT",
        "pt": []
      },
      {
        "sbs_id": 455654445,
        "dt": "IPTV",
        "pt": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

JsonPath that I wrote:

```
$.data.sbs[0].pt[0]
```

Assertion that Karate gave:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: base-tvpp-cases.feature:316 
- path: $[0], actual: null, expected: null, reason: actual json-path does 
not exist
```

Gherkin-Karate- code that I wrote in feature file:
I tried both below

```
And match response.data.subscribers[0].products[0] == null
And match response.data.subscribers[0].products[0] == '#null'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a JsonPath wildcard (`..` or `*`). Note that when you use a wildcard - the result will *always* be a JSON array. Here is your solution:

```
* match response.data..subscribers[0].products[0] == []
```