# How to access the value of a JsonPath array result (Karate assertion)

Tags: karate

My JSON response from an API:

```
{
    "args": {
        "param1": "valueA",
        "param2": "valueB"
    }
}
```

My karate assertions:

```rb
# ✅
And match response.args.param1 == "valueA"

# ❌ actual: ["valueB"], expected: "valueB"
And match $..param2 == "valueB"

# ❌ actual: [2], expected: 2, reason: not equal (JSONArray : Integer)
And match $..args.length() == 2
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55607609/675577) I understood that when I use a JsonPath wildcard, an array is always returned. So my question is how can I access the first and only element of that array, to use on my assertion? I tried appending `[0]` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonPath always returns an array, because it is a "search". So the moment you do `..` or `*` - that's how it is. You have to extract by index:

```
* match response..param1 == ['valueA']
* def temp = $..param1
* match temp[0] == 'valueA'
```

EDIT: if you really care about making the "intent" of getting the first element out of the JsonPath result, here you go:

```
* def temp = get[0] $..param1
* match temp == 'valueA'
```

Comment: Your code works. But like I said, appending `[0]` like `And match $..param1[0] == "valueA"` doesn't work: `path: $..param1[0], actual: [], expected: 'valueA', reason: actual value is not a string`. Why doesn't this work without the tmp var?

Comment: So you're saying that I either **(1)** match with an array on the "expected value" or **(2)** store the result in a tmp var just to make the assertion later. I feel option 1 is misleading, because whoever reads the test will think the API returns an array, which is false, it's just a hack to deal with JsonPath. And option 2 is just cumbersome.

Comment: @dialex karate is open source, so you are welcome to submit a PR. look JsonPath is tricky, it works well for arrays, not the cumbersome hacky field-level stuff you are trying to do. `$[*].foo[0]` does NOT mean the first element of the result of `$[*].foo`. can you point me to other frameworks which can do this in a less hacky way, we can learn from it - also see my edit