# Make karate to throw error when there is null result from jsonPath expression

Tags: karate

Json:

```
    def a = {
    "list1":[
        {
            "key":[]
        },
        {
            "key":[]
        }
    ],
    "list2":[
        {
            "key":[]
        },
        {
            "key":[]
        }
    ]
     
 }
```

Now for this jsonPath expression will be `$..key` it throws null result

If i try from karate `And match each a..key == ${someexpectedvalue}` since the array doesn't meets the expected result it should throw error but now it is getting passed

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62281362/143475